# R GC() Garbage collection on CMD Batch execution time

Tags: r, windows, garbage-collection

When executing a CMD Batch on a server R scripts take a long time to start as borne out in the ROut file. 
Switching on Verbose shows GC is running for around 10 minutes for all scripts, these scripts run fine in RStudio

Here is the command line in the task scheduler 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\R.exe” CMD BATCH "\Server-Directory\RFilename.R"

The ROut file looks like this/ 
As I said, this does not happen when running in RStudio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

---

```
'verbose' and 'quietly' are both true; being verbose then ..
now dyn.load("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/methods/libs/x64/methods.dll") ...

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Garbage collection 1 = 0+0+1 (level 2) ... 
5.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (29%)
1.4 Mbytes of vectors used (17%)
Garbage collection 2 = 0+1+1 (level 1) ... 
15.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
7.4 Mbytes of vectors used (94%)
Garbage collection 3 = 0+1+2 (level 2) ... 
17.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (71%)
7.9 Mbytes of vectors used (68%)
Garbage collection 4 = 0+1+3 (level 2) ... 
23.0 Mbytes of cons cells used (73%)
10.5 Mbytes of vectors used (72%)
Garbage collection 5 = 0+1+4 (level 2) ... 
27.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (68%)
11.7 Mbytes of vectors used (59%)
Garbage collection 6 = 0+1+5 (level 2) ... 
27.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
17.9 Mbytes of vectors used (66%)
Garbage collection 7 = 0+1+6 (level 2) ... 
27.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
27.2 Mbytes of vectors used (71%)
Garbage collection 8 = 0+1+7 (level 2) ... 
27.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
36.5 Mbytes of vectors used (74%)
Garbage collection 9 = 0+1+8 (level 2) ... 
27.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
49.0 Mbytes of vectors used (76%)
Garbage collection 10 = 0+1+9 (level 2) ... 
27.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
63.5 Mbytes of vectors used (75%)
Garbage collection 11 = 0+1+10 (level 2) ... 
27.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
80.3 Mbytes of vectors used (76%)
Garbage collection 12 = 0+1+11 (level 2) ... 
27.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
102.6 Mbytes of vectors used (78%)
Garbage collection 13 = 0+1+12 (level 2) ... 
27.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
130.4 Mbytes of vectors used (79%)
Garbage collection 14 = 0+1+13 (level 2) ... 
29.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (58%)
164.4 Mbytes of vectors used (80%)
Garbage collection 15 = 0+1+14 (level 2) ... 
33.9 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
204.1 Mbytes of vectors used (80%)
Garbage collection 16 = 0+1+15 (level 2) ... 
33.9 Mbytes of cons cells used (54%)
248.8 Mbytes of vectors used (81%)
Garbage collection 17 = 1+1+15 (level 0) ... 
62.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (100%)
300.4 Mbytes of vectors used (98%)
Garbage collection 18 = 1+1+16 (level 2) ... 
62.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (81%)
298.4 Mbytes of vectors used (81%)
Garbage collection 19 = 1+1+17 (level 2) ... 
63.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (67%)
364.6 Mbytes of vectors used (58%)
Garbage collection 20 = 1+1+18 (level 2) ... 
94.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (82%)
541.5 Mbytes of vectors used (72%)
Garbage collection 21 = 1+1+19 (level 2) ... 
115.7 Mbytes of cons cells used (82%)
562.3 Mbytes of vectors used (62%)
Garbage collection 22 = 1+1+20 (level 2) ... 
140.9 Mbytes of cons cells used (82%)
577.8 Mbytes of vectors used (64%)
Garbage collection 23 = 1+1+21 (level 2) ... 
171.2 Mbytes of cons cells used (82%)
595.1 Mbytes of vectors used (65%)
Garbage collection 24 = 1+1+22 (level 2) ... 
207.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
615.9 Mbytes of vectors used (68%)
Garbage collection 25 = 1+1+23 (level 2) ... 
251.3 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
656.9 Mbytes of vectors used (60%)
Garbage collection 26 = 1+1+24 (level 2) ... 
303.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
686.9 Mbytes of vectors used (63%)
Garbage collection 27 = 1+1+25 (level 2) ... 
366.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
722.8 Mbytes of vectors used (66%)
Garbage collection 28 = 1+1+26 (level 2) ... 
441.9 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
798.1 Mbytes of vectors used (61%)
Garbage collection 29 = 1+1+27 (level 2) ... 
532.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
850.1 Mbytes of vectors used (65%)
Garbage collection 30 = 1+1+28 (level 2) ... 
641.0 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
912.6 Mbytes of vectors used (70%)
Garbage collection 31 = 1+1+29 (level 2) ... 
771.4 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
987.8 Mbytes of vectors used (63%)
Garbage collection 32 = 1+1+30 (level 2) ... 
927.8 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
1141.0 Mbytes of vectors used (60%)
Garbage collection 33 = 1+1+31 (level 2) ... 
1115.5 Mbytes of cons cells used (83%)
1248.3 Mbytes of vectors used (66%)
Garbage collection 34 = 1+1+32 (level 2) ... 
1261.6 Mbytes of cons cells used (78%)
1885.0 Mbytes of vectors used (83%)
```

Comment: Try Rscript.exe instead?

Comment: Are you running Rstudio on the same machine? Do they have the same amount of RAM? It's not going to be easy to help you without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Machine has 32GB ram and the test was on the same and a different machine. I am wondering if there is a difference with Java when running CMD Batch versus RStudio? I would share the code if I could, but this is prior to any code execution so I doubt it would help.

Comment: Just tried with an empty Script file with the same result.

Comment: RScript does not suffer from this problem. Thanks for the suggestion A.Webb

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for CMD BATCH, but A.Webb suggested using RScript instead. 
This works as the script now executes very quickly, but it lacks the ROut file.

**Was :** 
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\R.exe” CMD BATCH "\Server-Directory\RFilename.R"

**Now :**
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64\RScript.exe” "\Server-Directory\RFilename.R"